# Disable (#) of comboboxes located below another combobox based on its selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

Say I have multiple comboboxes stacked on top of one another.

```
**[_______] Combobox #1  
  [_______] Combobox #2  
  [_______] Combobox #3  
  [_______] Combobox #4  
  [_______] Combobox #5  
  [_______] Combobox #6  
  [_______] Combobox #7**
```

If at any time I select the drop down from a combobox which is fed from some list of values (for simplicity sake, lets say numbers 1-5), the value the combobox selects will disable that # of comboboxes below it. So if Combobox #1 selected a value "3" Comboboxes #2, #3, & #4 will be disabled or have some value associated like "0" to know it is now out. And Subsequently I can continue and say I select combobox #5 and select a value of "2" then in the end it would look something like this:

```
**[___3___] Combobox #1**  
  [_______] Combobox #2  
  [_______] Combobox #3  
  [_______] Combobox #4  
**[___2___] Combobox #5**  
  [_______] Combobox #6  
  [_______] Combobox #7
```

(Comboboxes 2,3,4,6,7 being disabled). I would also need to reset the process, meaning changing the selected value will change and update the number of disabled boxes accordingly.

Rough Idea in code of what I'd like to achieve:

```
private void combobox#_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, Eventargs e)  
{  
    for (x in combobox#.SelectedValue)  
        combobox[#+x].Enabled = false;  
}
```

Any ideas how to make this possible? Thank you! Ideally in C# winform but open to WPF if it provides a better solution.

Comment: `this.Controls.Find(controlName)` ought to help you.

Comment: Ahh this is one thing I've been looking for. So essentially would controlName be able to call the different comboboxes in the for loop?

Comment: do you generate the fields dynamically? show your code

Comment: Sounds like this is the case when you don't want to write a lot of code in  `selectedValueChanged` events. Only this - You need to write controller class with combo boxes values matrix. And when any value change occurs, stop event handling and set the values according to matrix , then resume event handling

Comment: @T.S. a matrix and controller sounds like the right idea. Mind sharing a simple example?

Comment: 11 pm and still working. May be later.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Put your combo boxes in a list or an array, something like:

```
var comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox> { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3, ... };
```

Then use code like you have, but use an array index instead of trying to compose the name.  Remember that a collection of combo boxes (or of any other reference type) is just a collection of object references.  They don't cost very much.

Comment: I still can't quite figure out what you're doing, or more importantly, why. But the answer to the comments' question is easy. Say two things are disabled, and you did something to indicate that a different set of three things should be disabled. Walk through the list, enable everything except for the ones you want newly disabled. You can set enabled to false on something that's already disabled (which won't change anything). Don't just loop through the ones you want disabled, loop through every item and enable or disable as appropriate.